# Parentheses with automatically increasing heights

Tags: math-mode, delimiters, size, parentheses

To reflect the way I draw math by hand, and because I find this more readable, I would like to have `\left` and `\right` (or a custom pair of commands) render parentheses‐like symbols with an increasing size, even if their actual content does not get taller.

As is, the code:

```
\left(\left(\left(\left(a\right)\right)\right)\right)
```

renders as:

[image: all parentheses are the same size]

I am seeking something *roughly* looking like:

[image: parentheses are of increasing sizes, the outer the bigger]

Of course, just as `\left` and `\right`, it would have to work automatically, that is, I wouldn’t have to specify any size information manually. My guess is that `\left` and `\right` measure the height of what is between them and compute an appropriate size for the parentheses. So, it might do the trick to alter their behaviour so that they pretend their parentheses to be slightly taller than how they are actually rendered — say, by a 1.2 factor, or whatever.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `\delimiterfactor = 1200`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Duplicate indeed. Sorry I didn’t found that question while browsing this website.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti: That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Shame on me for not having found it *via* my search engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath}

\delimiterfactor = 1200



\begin{document}

Text before.
\[
    \left(\left(\left(\left(\left(\left(
        (a)
    \right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)
\]
Text after.

\end{document}
```

Note that changes to `\delimiterfactor` obey normal scoping rules.